# Using HMAC vs EVP functions in OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl, hmac

This is a very basic question, but what is the difference between EVP and HMAC? EVP is a message digest, but how does that differ from what is generated by HMAC?

Answer (score 7):

> ... what is the difference between EVP and HMAC

`EVP_*` functions are a high level interface. `HMAC_*`, `AES_*` and friends are lower level primitives. You can work with either, but its recommended you work with the `EVP_*` functions. The `HMAC_*` routines are software based and don't use hardware.

The `EVP_*` functions will allow you to easily swap in different hashes and the code essentially remains the same. And you will take advantage of hardware acceleration, like AES-NI for an AES-CMAC, if available.

Here's an OpenSSL example based on https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_DigestInit.html.

```
EVP_MD_CTX* mdctx = NULL;
const EVP_MD* md = NULL;

unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
int md_len = 0;

char message[] = "Now is the time for all good men to "
    "come to the aide of their country\n";

OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA1");
mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();

if(!EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL))
    handleError();

if(!EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, message, strlen(message)))
    handleError();

if(!EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len))
    handleError();

if(!EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx))
    handleError();

printf("Digest is: ");
for(int i = 0; i < md_len; i++)
    printf("%02x", md_value[i]);
printf("\n");
```

Now, and HMAC is slightly different than a Hash. The HMAC is a keyed hash, while the hash is not keyed. You can also use the `EVP_*` functions for HMAC'ing. Below is from the OpenSSL's wiki page [EVP Signing and Verifying](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying):

```
EVP_MD_CTX* mdctx = NULL;
const EVP_MD* md = NULL;
EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;

unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];   
int md_len = 0;

char message[] = "Now is the time for all good men to "
    "come to the aide of their country\n";

OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

if(!(mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create()))
    handleError();

if(!(md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA1")))
    handleError();

if(!(pkey = EVP_PKEY_new_mac_key(EVP_PKEY_HMAC, NULL, "password", strlen("password"))))
    handleError();

if(1 != EVP_DigestSignInit(mdctx, NULL, md, NULL, pkey))
    handleError();

/* Call update with the message */
if(1 != EVP_DigestSignUpdate(mdctx, message, strlen(message)))
    handleError();

if(1 != EVP_DigestSignFinal(mdctx, md_value, &md_len))
    handleError();

printf("HMAC is: ");
for(int i = 0; i < md_len; i++)
    printf("%02x", md_value[i]);
printf("\n");
```

The low level interface would look similar to:

```
EVP_MD_CTX* mdctx = NULL;
const EVP_MD* md = NULL;

unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
int md_len = 0;

char message[] = "Now is the time for all good men to "
"come to the aide of their country\n";

OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA1");
mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();

if(!HMAC_Init_ex(mdctx, key, sizeof(key), md, NULL))
    handleError();

if(!HMAC_Update(mdctx, message, strlen(message)))
    handleError();

if(!HMAC_Final(mdctx, md_value, &md_len))
    handleError();

if(!HMAC_CTX_cleanup(mdctx))
    handleError();

printf("HMAC is: ");
for(int i = 0; i < md_len; i++)
    printf("%02x", md_value[i]);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: There is a major problem with your code.  ```key``` is not an ```unsigned char``` array it's an ```EVP_PKEY```.  Also, there are some typos.

Comment: I have dug out how to create the EVP_PKEY (more at http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Key_and_Parameter_Generation)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use EVP_PKEY_new_mac_key function in order to obtain the right key structure for HMAC. And don't forget to free it with EVP_PKEY_free.