# Progress Bar With SHA256 Hashing in ANSI C

Tags: c, hash, sha256

For a project that I am working on right now, I was wondering how I could add a progress indicator to the Openssl SHA256 hashing function. I will be working with some large files (1-10+ GB) and would like to be able to see the progress completed versus left. I have implemented the Stack Overflow questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262386/generate-sha256-with-openssl-and-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284420/how-to-use-sha1-hashing-in-c-programming), and have the SHA256 hash generating working correctly (it only lacks a progress indicator).

I am fairly new to C, so this will be a learning experience for me. I thought that I might be able to use fread or SHA256_Update somehow, but I am having trouble understanding exactly how I would get a response of how much of the file has been read.

---

```
char _genSHA256Hash(char *path, char outputBuffer[65])
{
  FILE *file = fopen(path, "rb");
  if(!file) return -1;

  unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
  SHA256_CTX sha256;
  SHA256_Init(&sha256);
  const int bufSize = 32768;
  char *buffer = malloc(bufSize);
  int bytesRead = 0;
  if(!buffer) return -1;
  while((bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, bufSize, file)))
  {
      SHA256_Update(&sha256, buffer, bytesRead);
  }
  SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);

  sha256_hash_string(hash, outputBuffer);

  //fclose(file);
  //free(buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I have added the sha256_hash_string function:

```
void sha256_hash_string (unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH], char outputBuffer[65]) {
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        sprintf(outputBuffer + (i * 2), "%02x", hash[i]);
    }

    outputBuffer[64] = 0;
}
```

---

Thank you,

Tim

Comment: You'll need a `stat` or some such to tell you how big the file is, then do the math for delta yourself while the loop iterates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have information about how much of the file has been read, you just need to account for it:

```
int bytesRead = 0;
int totRead = 0;
while((bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, bufSize, file))) {
    totRead += bytesRead;
    ...
```

All you need now is the total size of the file. You can get this with:

```
struct stat sb;
if (stat(path, &sb) == -1) {
    perror("stat");
    return 0;
}
```

`totRead` keeps a running counter; bytesRead is reset each time through the loop. Then, in your loop, `totRead / sb.st_size` represents the percentage of your hashing progress.

Comment: It returns char because I call the function like so: "char buffer[65]; _genSHA256Hash("file", buffer); printf("%s\n", buffer);" I guess I could have made the function void though and just print the value inside the function itself and not return anything.

Comment: The function modifies the data inside the array in the buffer passed to it, which is not the same as the return type. It's idiomatic to return `int` in these cases -- `char` is weird because it's basically guaranteed that nobody is going to call this function and interpret its result as a character.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I think I got momentarily confused. I will change the _genSHA256Hash function to return void or int.

Comment: It appears that when I try to print the size of the file read versus left, bytesRead is always at value 32768. I added the following statement to the while loop: 'printf("percent done: %d of %zu\n", bytesRead, sb.st_size);' I can upload a screenshot somewhere for you to look at, but it looks like bytesRead is always the integer 32768 and then it suddenly stops and breaks out of the loop. Thanks, Tim

Comment: Here is a photo: http://pbrd.co/1tIrH2J and here is a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/qiNz6uNh

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot. bytesRead is going to be your fread buffer size each time, which is bufSize, which is 32768. You will need to keep a running counter. I'll update my response.